# Generic RETURN_IF_FALSE() macro?

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to clean up some legacy code that contains hundreds of functions with bodies that look like this:

```
void functionWithSideEffect(Foo* foo)
{
    if (foo)
    {
        // Use `foo' to warm the planet
        ...
    }
}
```

Obviously, *silently* failing if a precondition check fails isn't the best idea, so I'd like to refactor this to:

```
int functionWithSideEffect(Foo* foo)
{
    RETURN_IF_FALSE(foo != NULL, "foo is NULL in functionWithSideEffect!");

    // Use `foo' to warm the planet
    ...
}
```

The following macro seems to work fine for functions that don't return a value:

```
#define RETURN_IF_FALSE(cond, msg) \
  do { \
      if (!(cond)) { \
          LOG("%s\n", (msg)); \
          assert((cond)); \
      } \

      return; \
  } while(0)
```

And it has the following desirable properties:

- It is clear and succinct in usage
- It does *not* silently fail
- It will crash in debug builds, but attempt to soldier on in release builds

(Admittedly, for functions returning `void`, soldiering on in release builds may not always be 'desirable'.)

For functions that *do* return a value, this macro does the trick:

```
#define RETURN_VALUE_IF_FALSE(cond, msg, retval ) \
  do { \
      if (!(cond)) { \
          LOG("%s\n", (msg)); \
          assert((cond)); \
      } \
      return(retval); \
  } while(0)
```

My question is: is it possible to write a *single* `RETURN_IF_FALSE` macro to handle both `void` functions *and* functions returning a value? I sat down to attempt something using a varargs macro and quickly discovered I'm not very good at writing complex macros. I started out with this test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define RETURN_IF_FALSE(cond, msg, ... ) \
  do { \
      if (!(cond)) { \
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", (msg)); \
          assert((cond)); \
      } \
      return (##__VA_ARGS__); \
  } while(0)


int main()
{
    RETURN_IF_FALSE(1 < 0, "1 is not less than 0!", -1);
    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps not surprisingly, it generated the following compile error:

```
g++     macro_test.cpp   -o macro_test
macro_test.cpp:10:14: error: pasting "(" and "-" does not give a valid preprocessing token
       return (##__VA_ARGS__); \
              ^
macro_test.cpp:16:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘RETURN_IF_FALSE’
     RETURN_IF_FALSE(1 < 0, "1 is not less than 0!", -1);
     ^
```

Is it even *possible* to cover both cases with a single macro? I'm using gcc 4.8.1 on Linux.  (I *can* compile with `-std=c++11`, if it helps...)

**UPDATE**: To bring this full-circle, here's the implementation I ultimately wound up with based on @Turix's answer and a suggestion from @Deduplicator to move the `assert()` call up to avoid a double evaluation of the conditional in the 'sunny day' case:

```
#define RETURN_IF_FALSE(cond, ... ) \
  do { \
      if (!(cond)) { \
          const char* msg = \
              "Pre-condition '" #cond "' not met, returning " #__VA_ARGS__ "..."; \
          LOG("%s\n", msg); \
          assert((cond)); \
          return __VA_ARGS__; \
      } \
  } while(0)
```

(I decided it wasn't really all that necessary/useful to allow setting of a 'free form' message string, so I just generated a canned one from the condition...)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If the pointer is null, you will get undefined behavior. If you want it to try and soldier on, throw an exception and something can catch it and try the next thing.

Comment: Why do you use the concatenation operator `##`? Leave it out, and it will compile.

Comment: You'll need either C++11 or some gnu extension to C++03 for variadic macros. (I'd suggest using the former, if you really need them.)

Comment: If it's a precondition error, just abort/terminate.  Don't return to the caller.  The calling code is broken.

Comment: Just a tip: Only evaluate `cond` once.

Comment: Why don't you just add an `else` clause to the `if(foo)` statement and make noise about the failure there?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, I agree, but many of my colleagues feel differently (see [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/216289/is-it-reasonable-to-null-guard-every-single-dereferenced-pointer) for some background).  Unless I change jobs, these checks _must_ remain. I'm just trying to make things better by ensuring they cause an assertion failure in debug builds, and don't fail _silently_ in release builds.

Comment: @Deduplicator, you mean move the ``assert()`` up in the ``if`` clause? Good idea, thanks. I'll modify the example in my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this part of your macro `return (##__VA_ARGS__);` with `return __VA_ARGS__ ;` and I think it should do what you want (assuming that what you would pass for the return value isn't a complex expression -- if it is, you would need to pre-wrap the parameter with parentheses).

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't try that, thanks for the suggestion, it seems to work fine. I'll post another comment here if I find any gotchas, but for now, this gets me what I wanted.

Comment: @evadeflow  Great.  Also, don't forget to do what Deduplicator suggested in his/her comment above. You only need to evaluate `cond` once.  So change your macro to just `assert(0);` if the if-branch is taken.

Comment: I moved the ``assert()`` up to keep the condition from being evaluated twice in the sunny day case, but kept the condition in place so that the output in the console from the failed assertion is more understandable when the condition is ``false``. (I'm not so worried about the redundant evaluation if we're about to exit, anyway, but getting it out of the main code path is a really good idea.)

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define RET_IF_FALSE(x, y, z) if (!x) { printf(y); return z; }


int a(int *p)
{
    RET_IF_FALSE(p, __FUNCTION__, 0);

    return *p;
}

void b(int *p)
{
    RET_IF_FALSE(p, __FUNCTION__, );
}


int main()
{
    int x;

    x = a(&x);
    b(&x);

    x = a(NULL);
    b(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

It may not be the prettiest solution with a trailing comma, and it isn't compliant with standards according to gcc's -pedantic option.

Using:

```
#define RET_IF_FALSE(x, y, ...) if (!x) { printf(y); return __VA_ARGS__; }
```

with the rest of the code the same works for gcc with pedantic and -std=c99, and with -std=c++11 in clang++ and g++. Not sure what MS compilers do, as their support for standards is a little less stellar at times (and I haven't got a Windows setup to test on at present).